# Get condition on $x$ from $|mx -a| < |mx-b|$

Tags: inequality

I have the inequality $|mx -a| < |mx-b|$, and I'm trying to get a condition or range for $x$ from it.

I squared the inequality to get

$$
a^2 - (2m a)x < b^2 - (2mb)x \\
\implies a^2-b^2 < 2mx(a-b) \\
\implies (a-b)(a+b) <2mx(a-b)\\
\implies (a+b)/2m< x
$$

However, I am confused by the fact that if I changed the arrangement of terms in the second line, I could just as well get
$$
(2mb)x - (2m a)x < b^2 - a^2 \\
\implies 2mx(b-a) < b^2-a^2 \\
\implies 2mx(b-a) < (b-a)(b+a)\\
\implies x < (b+a)/2m
$$

what am I doing wrong here? Is it invalid to cancel out $(b-a)$ (or $(a-b)$)?

Comment: When you cancel out $(b-a)$ or $(a-b)$ you don't know whether this quantity is positive or not and therefore whether the sign of the inequality should change or not. Actually, since either $b-a$ or $a-b$ is negative, only one of your solutions is true.

Comment: A small hint, if I were you I would first introduce a new variable $y=mx$, and get a condition on $y$. Extracting the condition for $x$ should then be simple.

Comment: @5xum I don't quite understand, $a^2 - 2ay$ < $b^2-2by \implies a^2-b^2 < 2y(a-b)$ or $2y(b-a) < b^2 -a^2$ and I'm back to the same issue...?

Comment: @FlorianIngels, thank you, I get it now. I tried out $ (-2)x > 3 (-2) x \implies x>3x$ which isn't true, so the sign of what I'm cancelling out will change the inequality.